# Why my OpenGL custom shader gives me this error?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, shader, cocos2d-x

I'm using a custom shader with cocos2d 3.17 for my macOS app on XCode11 but I have some troubles.

**myShader.frag**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
 precision lowp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 u_rotation;

void main()
{
  mat4 t1= mat4(1);
  mat4 t2= mat4(1);
  t1[3] = vec4(-0.5,-0.5,1,1);
  t2[3] = vec4(+0.5,+0.5,1,1);
  vec2 pos = (t2 * u_rotation * t1 * vec4(gl_PointCoord, 0, 1)).xy;
  gl_FragColor  =  v_fragmentColor * texture2D(u_texture, pos);
}
```

**myShader.vert**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
uniform float u_pointSize;
uniform lowp vec4 u_fragmentColor;
varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;

void main()
{
  gl_Position     = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
  gl_PointSize    = u_pointSize;
  v_fragmentColor = u_fragmentColor;
}
```

With this config I have this error:

> cocos2d: ERROR: 0:21: 'vec4' : syntax error: syntax error

regarding myShader.vert

I don't understand, seems good to me.

Answer (score 3):

The shader is written for [OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php) (GLSL ES 1.00). When you try to compile the shaders with ["desktop" OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php), then you'll get errors, because of the precision qualifiers.

Remove the precision qualifiers in the vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec4 a_position;
uniform float u_pointSize;
uniform vec4 u_fragmentColor;
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;

void main()
{
  gl_Position     = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
  gl_PointSize    = u_pointSize;
  v_fragmentColor = u_fragmentColor;
}
```

and the fragment shader:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
 precision lowp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 u_rotation;

// [...]
```

Precision qualifiers have been added in GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0) code portability (not for functionality) with OpenGL ES, however, they are not supported in previous versions.
(Since you have no version specified, you are using GLSL 1.00)

---

Alternatively you can use a macro for the precision qualifier:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp 
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

attribute vec4 a_position;
uniform float u_pointSize;
uniform LOWP vec4 u_fragmentColor;
varying LOWP vec4 v_fragmentColor;

// [...]
```

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision lowp float;
#define LOWP lowp 
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying LOWP vec4 v_fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 u_rotation;

// [...]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! I forgot to mention that this is a porting of a iOS app, this is the reason because this is written in OpenGLES.
I changed it but now it's appeared this error: cocos2d: ERROR: 0:33: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_PointCoord'
ERROR: 0:34: Use of undeclared identifier 'pos' for the myShader.frag... 
I supposed that's for the version, so i added #version 120 but cocos2d: ERROR: 0:18: '' :  #version must occur before any other statement in the program...

Comment: @ele_elion `gl_PointCoord` is available in any GLSL version. Did you confuse vertex and fragment shader? 2. `#version must occur before any` is caused by the fact, that cocos2d adds some code (probably macros) to the shader code.

Comment: I double checked and it is actually fragment shader that gives me the error .. what does this mean?

Comment: Another thing: I checked online and I discovered that there is a mistake in the OpenGL docs which state that gl_PointCoord is a 1.1 feature, whereas in fact it was introduced in 1.2.